# Conceptual Question About a Function's Domain When Deriving/Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

For my definition of a differentiable function, I am using the following:

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}, \enspace f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ and also $a \in X\cap X'$ ("a" belongs to $X$ and it is an accumulation point of $X$). Then we say $f$ is differentiable  at $a$ if the following limit exists:$$f'(a)= \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

But suppose I have the following **problem**:

---

Let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined at this interval "$I$". If there is $\alpha > 1$ such that  $ |f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|^{\alpha}$ for all $x, y \in I$. Show that $f$ is continuous and has derivative $0$ at all points of $I$.

---

**My problem is** that in my approach I'm not considering if the interval is open, closed, or if my points are accumulations points or not. I think I'm being reckless but don't know how to improve it.

Here is what I've done:

Since $ |f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|^{\alpha}$ for all $x, y \in I$, we have that

$$ \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \le |x-a|^{\alpha-1} \Rightarrow  \left|{\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}}\right| \le |x-a|^{\alpha-1}\qquad (\alpha-1) > 0$$

Now, if we fixate $y \in I$ we can simply take the limits on both sides and use the fact that the modulus function is continuous:

$$|f'(y)|=\left|\lim_{x\to y}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right| \le \lim_{x\to y}|{x-y}|^{\alpha-1}=0$$

Since $y$ is any point in $I$ I can say that the derivative exists at every point of $I$ and it is $0$. Also, given we have the derivatives, we know the function to be continuous.

But, as you can see, I didn't take the lateral limits and, if we had chosen, for example, $y$ to be sup or inf of $I$, wouldn't this be a problem?

Comment: I would say that if $y$ were not an accumulation point for $f$, then the function $$\phi(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y},$$which is not defined in $y$, *would not be defined in a whole sufficiently small interval containing $y$*, so I guess the comparison with $|x-y|^{\alpha-1}$ would not be possibile in such interval.